Closed loop motor speed algorithms
TLDR; looking for algorithms to control a motor. I have a near-random torque, a battery current that can destroy my motor driver, and I aim for a stable output speed regardless of torque. My inputs are current as reported by the motor driver, and a rotary encoder.
Google led me to PID (proportional, integral, derivative) motor control. That doesn't stop drawing too much current when the motor stalls/starts. Looking at internet examples, PID also seems more suited for predictable or more tunable loads. I'm trying to avoid reinvent the wheel. Is there some algorithm/library that handles this? Should this be a hardware/electrical safety?
Background
I'm building a mechanical walker robot for an art show along with two master students. They're a bit behind and I'm helping out with the code (approved by their profs). I can code but I lack insight in the control algorithms that I can implement.
The walker has 6 segments. Each segment has 2 legs. The legs are moved with a linkage system, all tied together with a central drive to keep all legs in sync.
I have:

arduino nano
500W 24V brushed DC motor
BTS7960 43A motor controller dual H-bridge

L- and R- current sense readout of the controller


Rotary encoder
RC transceiver with a pressure sensitive trigger
Li-Ion battery packs that can supply 60A
A 6 meter (20ft) 12-legged walker with variable torque between -3 and 10Nm

As the legs go round, there is a function (from simulation and measurements) to get the expected torque for a certain leg position on a flat surface. As soon as we hit a bump in the road, the balance shifts and we have no idea. I guess I should consider torque to be random.


Walking speed that is +-1000rpm (30:1 gear reduction in drive shaft to legs)

My goals:

more or less constant speed, regardless of torque
don't burn the controller/motor

current protection for startup/stall ?



Current status:

motor spins depending on RC trigger (no load)
rotary encoder signal is coming in
current sense is still troublesome, but I found a video. Hope to have that working soon
copy-pasted implementation of PID, but without load this doesn't do much

Any advice is appreciated, especially if I'm doing something stupid. It's a broad topic to quickly wrap my head around.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As soon as you said "walker" -- yup, you've chosen a hard road to -- err -- walk.  Why do we have wheelchairs and not walk-chairs?  Is it because it's cool to be stymied by stairways?  Or is there an underlying technical reason?


The walker has 6 segments. Each segment has 2 legs. The legs are moved with a linkage system, all tied together with a central drive to keep all legs in sync.


...get the expected torque for a certain leg position on a flat surface. As soon as we hit a bump in the road, the balance shifts and we have no idea...

This means that, in a walk cycle, a leg in contact with the (bumpy) ground will transmit back to the motor, the reaction force from the ground.
Since the legs are all linked, the power output by the motor is wasted opposing the reaction forces. The reaction forces will be very high if the road surface and the leg mechanisms are rigid (high stiffness / high modulus of elasticity).
Option 1
Introduce compliance into the system. Give the legs a soft padding or a spring so that the legs in contact with the ground don't generate high reaction forces which the motor need to oppose. Another option is to make the ground softer; e.g. a layer of sand or gravel
The smaller, and more even the reaction forces, the easier it will be for your motor controller to maintain constant speed.
Option 2
Independent drives for legs with force measuring sensors on each foot. When the legs touch the ground, sensors will sense reaction force from the ground, stop giving motion command to those legs. Those legs should switch over to a force control PID instead of a position control PID.

Make an inner loop that controls current in closed loop, then wrap that with an outer loop that controls speed.  I'm going to call them "current loop" and "speed loop" from here.
Make sure the bandwidth of the current loop is significantly higher (10x is the rule of thumb) than that of the speed loop.  If you don't know what "loop bandwidth" means, then figure that the inner loop needs to respond to disturbances about 10 times faster than the outer loop or this whole thing won't work.
Because speed is sorta-kinda the integral of torque (it would be exactly if there was neither friction nor disturbance), you probably don't need PID control -- you can probably use proportional-integral on both loops.  I recommend this, because differential control can be troublesome, especially to a beginner (you can overheat motors without even noticing, for one).
Tune the inner current loop in isolation (an oscilloscope will be your friend here).  You're looking for the fastest response you can get without ringing.  You may want to use some feed-forward (i.e., just add in some of the command to the final drive signal, outside of the error feedback).  Don't succumb to the temptation to tune that loop along with the outer loop.
When you're done tuning the current loop, tune the speed loop to the best performance you can get and then stop.  If you need more performance at this point, you need to call or become a professional -- this control loop stuff has a lot of nuances, many of which lead to damaged equipment or embarrassing performance in the field.
Use integrator anti-windup on any loop with an integrator.  Both of your loops have limited actuator authority (i.e.: you can't ask for 110% PWM duty cycle, and you shouldn't ask for more than your motor's rated torque).  This means you need anti-windup.

I know this is late (thank StackExchange for coughing up questions out of chronological order, and me for not paying attention).  Hopefully it's helpful to someone none the less.
